# href Hyperlink,Anchor Tage regular expression php error

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, anchor, syntax-error

**look at this and help me to fix this as work..this was not worked..**

```
$text = "Hello I am the PHP.go from here http://php.net"
$pattern = "/http:\/\/(www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.\s]+\.?[^.\s]*)/i";
$replace = "<a href='http://\\1\\2'>http://\\1\\2</a>";
$string =  preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$text);
echo $string;
```

**this is the error it shows.**

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pattern' (T_VARIABLE) in
```

Comment: add a ; at the end of the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is as written here, you are missing a semicolon from the end of $text.